# Scheme - Check if element of list is a single letter

Tags: scheme

I have a list `` `(+ 1 2 3 a b c) ``

I want to check if an element is a letter.

`(symbol? (list-ref mylist idx))` will return `#t` for both `a` and `+`, which I don't want.

Perhaps I could compare the element to `[a-zA-z]`, or check if it's a symbol that's not `[+-*/]`, but that seems tedious.

How is this done?

**Update:**

Actually, I could just write my own function.

```
(define is-letter
  (lambda (c)
    (if (and (not (number? c))
         (not (eq? c `+)) (not (eq? c `-)) (not (eq? c `*)) (not (eq? c '/)))
      #t
      #f
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Note that all of the items in your sample list _are_ symbols and numbers.  If you want to include real _characters_ in a list you must use their literal values, e.g. `'(#\+ #\1 #\2 #\3 #\a #\b #\c)`  You could then use `char-alphabetic?` to see if they are letter characters, or `char-numeric?` to identify numeric characters, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but I do want to use symbols.

Comment: Then I think you should be clear in your question that you are interested in the string representation of the name of any symbols in in the list, and perhaps furthermore in the characters that make up that string representation.  I think the concept of symbol names is quite important to get right in learning Scheme (or lisp).  Confusing symbols, or more properly the names of symbols, with strings is all too easy to do, and it would seem from the way that you tried to define your `is-letter` function that is exactly what you have done.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear in my question? I say I want to check if a symbol is a letter which I think is clear from my example and the function in my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you intend to use a quoted list, here's a possible solution that works by converting symbols to strings and then checking for the condition:

```
(define (is-single-letter? x)
  (if (number? x)
      #f
      (let ((s (symbol->string x)))
        (and (= (string-length s) 1)
             (char-alphabetic? (string-ref s 0))))))
```

For example:

```
(define mylist '(+ 1 2 3 a b c xxx))

(is-single-letter? (list-ref mylist 0)) ; + is an operator
=> #f

(is-single-letter? (list-ref mylist 2)) ; 2 is a number
=> #f

(is-single-letter? (list-ref mylist 4)) ; a is a single letter
=> #t

(is-single-letter? (list-ref mylist 7)) ; xxx is not a single letter
=> #f
```

Comment: I intend to use quoting though, so I would need another approach. My update does what I need - I was just wondering if there's a built-in way.

Comment: @Pushkin ok, I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Much better than my approach.